# How to pass id to other activity if my list view is created by JSON objects when clicked

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I am create a list view using json to retrieve data from server and showing the information in list view, i try to check whether the id is successfully passed into adapter by clicking the list will showing a snackbar, but i dont know how to pass the id into list view. Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);

    if(integer == 1)
    {
        //ADAPTER
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(c,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,players);

        //ADAPT TO LISTVIEW
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //LISTENET
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Snackbar.make(view,players.get(position),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to Parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    pd.dismiss();
}

//PARSE RECEIVED DATA
private int parse()
{
    try
    {
        //ADD THAT DATA TO JSON ARRAY FIRST
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(data);

        //CREATE JO OBJ TO HOLD A SINGLE ITEM
        JSONObject jo=null;

        players.clear();

        //LOOP THRU ARRAY
        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

            //RETRIOEVE NAME
            String name=jo.getString("campaign_name");
            String id=jo.getString("campaign_id");

            //ADD IT TO OUR ARRAYLIST
            players.add(name);
        }

        return 1;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output

[image]

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(id[position]),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 2):

Create a model class **Campaign** with fields **name** and **id**, and override **toString** to return whatever you want to display in the listview ( in your case name)

Pass a list of Campaign instead of list of string in the adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<Campaign> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Campaign>(..)`
```

In the parse method,

```
Campaign campaign = new Campaign()
campaign.name=jo.getString("campaign_name");
campaign.id=jo.getString("campaign_id");
players.add(campaign);`
```

Lastly, onItemclick

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Campaign item =     parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)
Snackbar.make(view,item.id +" "+item.name,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: If the requirement is just to display a single text in the listview, there should not be a need to create custom adaptor.The ArrayAdapter class takes arbitrary Object and not just String class

Answer (score 1):

In same way as created `players` ArrayList for `campaign_name`, create one more ArrayList for `campaign_id` add store all id's in it.

In `onItemClick` method use  `campaign_id` ArrayList for id of clicked item :

**1.** Create a ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrCampaignID=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**1.** Change `parse()` as:

```
       String id=jo.getString("campaign_id");

        //ADD IT TO OUR ARRAYLIST
        players.add(name);
        arrCampaignID.add(id);
```

**2.** In `onItemClick` use `arrCampaignID` to get selected campaign id:

```
@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id) {
       String str_compaign_id=  arrCampaignID.get(position);        
 }
```

Note , you can also do it by creating a custom class object with name and id properties, but in this case you need to create a custom Adapter by extending ArrayAdapter.